# Why is my code telling me that .draw is not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I created this game where the player is controlling a basket to catch random fruits.

my code is telling me that .draw is not a function at first.draw(); (which is drawing the first fruit in my array) and i made a draw function after creating a class for the fruit. so i'm not too sure what I have to do to fix this problem.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var basket = new Image();
basket.src = "basket.png";

var basketHeight = 50;
var basketWidth = 100;
var basketX = 200;
var basketY = canvas.height-50;
var basketSpeed = 5; //vary with superpowers

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

var score = 10;

var strawberry = new Image();
strawberry.src = "strawberry.png";

var banana = new Image();
banana.src = "banana.png";

var orange = new Image();
orange.src = "orange.png";


class Fruit{

  constructor(fruitX, fruitY, fruitType){
    this.fruitX = fruitX;//each fruit has a x
    this.fruitY = fruitY;//each fruit has a y
    this.fruitWidth = 100;//each fruit has a width of 100
    this.fruitHeight = 50;//each fruit has a height of 50
    this.isVisible = true;//fruit is visible
    this.fruitSpeed = 1;//fruit moves by 1 
    this.fruitType = fruitType;//fruit type
    this.fruitImage = new Image();//fruit image


    if(fruitType == strawberry){//if the fruittype (comparing it with funciton randomfruit) is a strawberry, then make the image a strawberry
        fruitImage= 'Images/strawberry.png';
    }
    else if(fruitType == banana){
      fruitImage = 'Images/banana.png';
    }
    else if(fruitType == orange){
      fruitImage = 'Images/orange.png';
    }
  }

  draw(){
     ctx.drawImage(this.fruitImage, this.fruitX, this.fruitY, this.fruitWidth, this.fruitHeight);
  }
}

function randomFruit(){//function is to generate a random fruit

  var fruitchoices = ['strawberry', 'banana', 'orange'];
  //array has strawberry, banana, orange
  var fruit = fruitchoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitchoices.length)]// choose random element from above

  var fruitX = Math.random() * (480-0);//declaring the variables so that we don't have to copy and paste this each time into the fruitX value since it will be the same for every fruit initally
  var fruitY = 0//set the y value of the fruit to 0
//compares the selected fruit with these statements
  if(fruit == 'strawberry'){
     new Fruit(fruitX,fruitY, 'strawberry');//if fruit is strawberry, make the fruit a strawberry 
  }
  else if(fruit == 'banana'){
    new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, 'banana');
  }
  else if(fruit == 'orange'){
    new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, 'orange');
  }    
  return fruit;//returns fruit value 
  }



//function for the fruits to move down the screen
function moveFruit(){ 
  fruits[i].Y += fruits[i].fruitSpeed;//the y value of the fruits in the array will be added by the fruit speed
}



document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);  // arguments "keydown" is the event
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);    //  keyDownHandler is the function that gets called



                                // when the event occurs
function keyDownHandler(e){
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e){
  if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}



function drawScore() {
   ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Score:" + score, canvas.width - 100, 20);
}



//drawing the game onto the screen
function drawGame() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clears top left to bottom right
  drawScore();

  //update basket position/controlling basket movement
  if(rightPressed) {
    basketX += basketSpeed;

    if(basketX + basketWidth > canvas.width){
      basketX = canvas.width - basketWidth;
    }

  }

  else if (leftPressed) {
    basketX -= basketSpeed;

    if(basketX < 0){
      basketX = 0;
    }
  }


  // loop thru each fruit
  for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    // check each fruit y value. if it is less than ?? draw new random fruit
  }


  moveFruit();

}


var first = randomFruit(); //variable first is set to a randomfruit from the function randomfruit
first.draw();//drawing the first fruit
fruits.add(first);//adding the first fruit to array so that we can keep track of it for the purpose of creating our second fruit image since we want a new fruit when the first fruit passes a certain y value

var interval = setInterval(drawGame, 10);//drawing whatever is in the function drawGame every 10 milliseconds
```

the first.draw is not working

```
var first = randomFruit(); //variable first is set to a randomfruit from the function randomfruit
first.draw();//drawing the first fruit
fruits.add(first);//adding the first fruit to array so that we can keep track of it for the purpose of creating our second fruit image since we want a new fruit when the first fruit passes a certain y value
```

Comment: `randomFruit` should return a `Fruit` to assign to `first`

Comment: i have added a return in my randomFruit function and it is still not working. I'm not sure if I did it correctly

Answer (score 1):

In your `randomFruit` function

```js
function randomFruit(){//function is to generate a random fruit

  var fruitchoices = ['strawberry', 'banana', 'orange'];
  //array has strawberry, banana, orange
  var fruit = fruitchoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitchoices.length)]// choose random element from above

  var fruitX = Math.random() * (480-0);//declaring the variables so that we don't have to copy and paste this each time into the fruitX value since it will be the same for every fruit initally
  var fruitY = 0//set the y value of the fruit to 0
//compares the selected fruit with these statements
  if(fruit == 'strawberry'){
     new Fruit(fruitX,fruitY, 'strawberry');//if fruit is strawberry, make the fruit a strawberry 
  }
  else if(fruit == 'banana'){
    new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, 'banana');
  }
  else if(fruit == 'orange'){
    new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, 'orange');
  }    
  return fruit;//returns fruit value 
}
```

You instantiated Fruit object but returns the fruit string (like 'orange') instead of the instantiated object. Therefore

```js
var first = randomFruit();
first.draw();
```

`first` is a string, `String.draw` is not a function.

try this:

```js
function randomFruit(){//function is to generate a random fruit

  var fruitchoices = ['strawberry', 'banana', 'orange'];
  //array has strawberry, banana, orange
  var fruit = fruitchoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitchoices.length)]// choose random element from above

  var fruitX = Math.random() * (480-0);//declaring the variables so that we don't have to copy and paste this each time into the fruitX value since it will be the same for every fruit initally
  var fruitY = 0//set the y value of the fruit to 0
//compares the selected fruit with these statements
  if(fruit == 'strawberry'){
     return new Fruit(fruitX,fruitY, 'strawberry');//if fruit is strawberry, make the fruit a strawberry 
  }
  else if(fruit == 'banana'){
    return new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, 'banana');
  }
  else if(fruit == 'orange'){
    return new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, 'orange');
  }    
  throw new Error('unexpected fruit');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `draw()` in `class Fruit`

You need to use `Fruit.draw()` to call your function.

Classes use scoping, so any function defined within it must use the class name to access the function.

Comment: `Fruit.draw` is not a static function, so it can't be called as `Fruit.draw()`

Answer (score 0):

As Hao-Cher Hong already have pointed out: your *randomFruit* returns a string, not the Fruit-object.

While looking at your code I see that you repeat yourself a lot. There are better ways.

May I suggest some refactoring?

For example in your constructor, you prefix every property with *fruit*, but since the whole object is a fruit, that is not necessary. Here is a cleaner example:

```
class Fruit {
  constructor(x, y, type) {
    this.x = x; //each fruit has a x
    this.y = y; //each fruit has a y
    this.width = 100; //each fruit has a width of 100
    this.height = 50; //each fruit has a height of 50
    this.isVisible = true; //fruit is visible
    this.speed = 1; //fruit moves by 1
    this.type = type; //fruit type
    this.typeData = Fruit.typeNameToData[type]; // // Get data for fruit

    if (!this.typeData) throw Error(`Unknown fruit: "${type}`); // Throw Error if unknown fruit
    this.image = new Image(); //fruit image
    this.image.src = this.typeData.image;
  }
}
```

Instead of defining the fruit names in several places in your code, do it once and reuse it. In this example I put the variable directly on the Fruit object. It is called *static*. Unfortunately the syntax for classes only supports static functions at this time, but it is possible to define variables directly like this:

```
// Define fruit types
Fruit.types = [
  {
    name: "strawberry",
    image: "Images/strawberry.png"
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    image: "Images/banana.png"
  },
  {
    name: "orange",
    image: "Images/orange.png"
  }
];
Fruit.typeNames = []; // List of typeNames
Fruid.typeNameToData = Object.create(null); // Create an empty object. Could also use a map, but I don't want to introduce too many new things at once.
Fruit.types.forEach(item => {
  // here is some "magic": Reusing the data from *Fruit.types* to create a lookup
  // for the name, and a list of names.
  Fruit.typeNameToData[item.name] = item; // Map name to data
  Fruit.typeNames.push(item.name); // add name to array
});
```

The *randomFruit* can be reduced to this:

```
function randomFruit() {
  //function is to generate a random fruit
  const fruitchoices = Fruit.typeNames; // Use list of fruits
  const fruitId = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitchoices.length);
  const fruitX = Math.random() * (480 - 0);
  const fruitY = 0;
  return new Fruit(fruitX, fruitY, fruitchoices[fruitId]);
}
```

I noticed that you are trying to use the global variable `i` here:

```
function moveFruit() {
  fruits[i].Y += fruits[i].fruitSpeed; //the y value of the fruits in the array will be added by the fruit speed
}
```

Do not use global variables like that. I promise you that you will create hard to find bugs, and you will accidentally change the variable in another loop. Add an argument to the function, and send the value that way.